# Incorrect output with Haskell function which uses lists and zip

Tags: list, haskell

My code is supposed to take a string, e.g. `ccccchhrrre` and return a list of pairs `[('c', 5) , ('h', 2) , ('r', 3), ('e', 1)]`.  The first part of the pair is a letter and the second part is the number of times it is repeated til the next string occurs.

Currently, however, my code returns `[('c',11)]` - which is the first character and length of the total number of characters in the string:

```
> fun4 "ccccchhrrre"
[('c',11)]
```

My issue is with `fun4`. When running *func3*

```
> fun3 "ccccchhrrre"
["ccccc","hh","rrr","e"]
```

```
fun3 :: String -> [String]
fun3 "" = [] 
fun3 xs = fun2 xs : fun3 (drop(length(fun2 xs))xs)

func4 :: String -> [(Char, Int)]
func4 fun3 = zip (fun3)[length fun3]
```

I appreciate any help that includes detailed explanations.

Comment: what is `fun2`?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of issues.  The first is that, when you write:

```
func4 :: String -> [(Char, Int)]
func4 fun3 = zip (fun3)[length fun3]
```

the `fun3` in this definition has absolute **nothing** to do with the `fun3` function you previously defined.  If you turned on compiler warnings (e.g., using the flag `-Wall`), it would warn you that the binding for `fun3` in this definition of `func4` "shadows" the existing binding.  This means that it's treated the same as if you'd used a complete separate name:

```
func4 :: String -> [(Char, Int)]
func4 bob = zip (bob) [length bob]
```

So, when you evaluate:

```
func4 "ccccchhrrre"
```

the function `fun3` isn't used at all.  Instead, it's expanded by the definition of `func4` to:

```
func4 "ccccchhrrre"
= zip "ccccchhrrre" [length "ccccchhrrre"]
= zip "ccccchhrrre" [11]
```

and since strings in Haskell are lists of characters, this is the same as:

```
= zip ['c','c',...] [11]
```

When you zip two lists and one is shorter than the other, the zip ends when the list runs out, so this yields:

```
= [('c', 11)]
```

and ignores the second and following elements of the character list.

What you probably wanted instead was to write `func4` to take a string argument and pass it to `fun3`:

```
func4 :: String -> [(Char, Int)]
func4 xs = zip (fun3 xs) [length (fun3 xs)]
```

Unfortunately, this won't type check.  The problem is that this is equivalent to:

```
func4 "ccccchhrrre"
= zip ["ccccc","hh","rrr","e"] [length ["ccccc","hh","rrr","e"]]
= zip ["ccccc","hh","rrr","e"] [4]
= [("ccccc", 4)]
```

which has type `[(String, Char)]` instead of the `[(Char, Char)]` you were expecting.

If you've learned about `map`, you may consider it useful to know that:

```
> map head ["ccccc","hh","rrr","e"]
"chre"
>
```

and `"chre"` is equivalent to the list `['c','h','r','e']`.  If you could somehow get a list of the lengths `[5,2,3,1]` the same way you got a list of the heads, these lists would zip up great.

If you don't want to use `map`, you might find it helpful to write a `func4` that processes the *output* of `fun3`, like so:

```
> func4 ["ccccc","hh","rrr","e"]
[('c',5),('h',2),('r',3),('e',1)]
>
```

It would have a slightly different signature, but a similar structure to your `fun3`:

```
func4 :: [String] -> [(Char, Int)]
func4 [] = []
func4 (str : strs) = ??? : func4 strs
```

and then your final function could chain `fun3` and `func4` together:

```
rle :: String -> [(Char, Int)]
rle str = func4 (fun3 str)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55563003/11301900) provides a good explanation of the problems in your code. Here is a slightly different solution, which I find easier to understand.

`fun3` can be replaced with an existing function, [`Data.List.group`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group). `group` takes a list and produces a list of lists, which contain adjacent elements which are equal:

```
> Data.List.group "ccccchhrrre"
["ccccc","hh","rrr","e"]
```

The work that `fun4` is supposed to perform can also be simplified by the use of `map`. The anonymous function `\x -> (head x, length x)` takes one argument `x`, and produces a tuple whose first element is the head of x, and whose second element is the length of x. Mapping this function over the output of `group` should give us the desired result:

```
> map (\x -> (head x, length x)) ["ccccc","hh","rrr","e"]
[('c',5),('h',2),('r',3),('e',1)]
```

We can now combine both `group` and our `map` into one function, and give it a more appropriate name:

```
-- Count adjacent repeated characters
countRep :: String -> [(Char, Int)]
countRep str = map (\x -> (head x, length x)) (List.group str)
```

#### Just for fun

The function we wrote can be used on any list whose items can be compared for equality! Here it is, in point-free style:

```
countRep :: Eq a => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
countRep = map (liftA2 (,) head length) . List.group
```